# Reactive Cocoa enable button based on text in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm having an issue with some really simple code in Reactive Cocoa and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm simply trying to bind the enabled state of a UIButton to a signal. That signal takes the text of a `UITextField` and runs it through a regex. This way I can enable the button when the regex matches.

This code gives me an exception while loading the View Controller:

```
// Poperties used in the view controller
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSRegularExpression *regex;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *continueButton;

// ... other stuff ...

// Code in my "view did load" method
RACSignal *mySignal = RACObserve(self, myTextField);

[mySignal deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];

@weakify(self);
[mySignal map:^(NSString *value) {
    @strongify(self);
    NSUInteger matches = [self.regex numberOfMatchesInString:value
                                                     options:0
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [value length])];
    return @(matches > 0);
}];

RAC(self.continueButton, enabled) = mySignal;
```

Clearly the exception explains that I'm trying to get the selector "enabled" from a `UITextField`, and the `UITextField` does not have this selector. I don't understand why I'm getting this error when I'm calling the enabled selector in my `continueButton`, not `myTextField`.

Basically the exception is:

```
[UITextField charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2c7830
```

And the debugger stops in the line:

```
[object setValue:x ?: nilValue forKeyPath:keyPath];
```

Instance `0xa2c7830` is a `UITextField`. `object` is a `UIButton` and `keyPath` is `@"enabled"`. I just don't see anything wrong with this setup, except that its being called on my `UITextField` instead of `UIButton`!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint is here:

```
[UITextField charValue]
```

The unrecognized selector isn't `enabled`; it's `charValue`. Okay, why would we be asking a `UITextField` to turn into a `char`? Well...if we wanted to cast it down to a boolean, then it's possible the KVO mechanics think it's an `NSNumber` and try to treat it as such. But it's not an `NSNumber` -- hence the exception.

But wait, didn't we map the signal to create an `NSNumber`? Why are we trying to cast it down to a boolean in the first place? And why is it a `UITextField` instead of an `NSString`? (We'll come back to that later)

Ah. Well, we actually didn't map the signal into something else, because `map:` isn't destructive.

By that I mean `map:` *creates a new signal*. It doesn't modify `mySignal`. We call `map:`, creating a new signal, but then we never do anything with it -- it just sits there, and nothing subscribes to it, and then it's deallocated. But we want to subscribe to it!

```
RAC(self.continueButton, enabled) = [mySignal map:^(NSString *value) {
    @strongify(self);
    NSUInteger matches = [self.regex numberOfMatchesInString:value
                                                     options:0
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [value length])];
    return @(matches > 0);
}];
```

Aha! Now we're binding the `enabled` property to the transformed signal -- which is what we wanted all along. But something is still amiss.

Something bad is going to happen when we try to do the regex match...if I had to guess `[UITextField length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xWhatever`

`UITextField` again? What's up with that guy?

The answer to that comes back to `mySignal`. What is `mySignal` *actually* sending? We want it to send text...but if that new exception I just made up is correct, it's sending a `UITextField`! Why? Well, `mySignal` is `RACObserve(self, myTextField)`. But wait! That will send new values of the text field -- not new values of the text field's text. What you want is:

```
RACSignal *mySignal = self.myTextField.rac_textSignal;
```

That will send new values of the text field's text, instead of new values of the text field.

Phew. That should work. As a tip: the `log*` helpers are very useful for debugging.

```
RAC(self.continueButton, enabled) = [mySignal logAll];
```

That'll show you that `mySignal` is sending `UITextField`s instead of `NSString`s.

Comment: A fantastic explanation, thank you so much. This is the best type of answer, because now I understand WHY it would not work. Feel much more comfortable with RAC now. Thanks again!